# Lucene tokenizer for generic source code

Tags: lucene, tokenize

I have a Lucene-based program that indexes source code files, and I noticed that Lucene's `StandardTokenizer` does not split words containing a dot, e.g. `foo.bar`. The problem with this is that in source code the dot is often is used in method calls, in which case the object name and method name should be separated.

So, my question is, how do I go about writing a custom `Tokenizer` that works well with source code in general (e.g. no specific programming language)? Are there any existing implementations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can check out [this article on onjava.com](http://onjava.com/onjava/2006/01/18/using-lucene-to-search-java-source.html) about indexing source code with Lucene, is some years old, but can serve as a guideline. Regarding tokenizer they use LowerCaseTokenizer that seems to do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the grammar (JFlex) of StandardTokenizer to split on dots, and generate your custom Tokenizer. This is what I did at [Generating a custom Tokenizer for new TokenStream API using JFlex/ Java CC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846305/generating-a-custom-tokenizer-for-new-tokenstream-api-using-jflex-java-cc).

OR

You can as well have a TokenFilter that splits on dots and create a custom Analyzer out of StandardTokenizer and this new TokenFilter. (See what StandardAnalyzer does and just insert this new TokenFilter in that).