# Searching for words like "UTTD_Equip_City_TE" in Lucene

Tags: java, lucene, rtf

Thanks for reading :)

I'm trying to search for words like "UTTD_Equip_City_TE" across RTF documents using Lucene. This word appears in two different forms:

- «UTTD_Equip_City_TE»,
- «UTTD_Equip_City_TE»

I first tried with StandardAnalyzer, but it seems to break down the word into "UTTD", "Equip", "City", and "TE".

Then I tried again using WhiteSpaceAnalyzer, but it doesn't seem to be working... (I don't know why).

Could you help me I should approach this problem? By the way, editing the Lucene source and recompiling it with Ant is not an option :(

Thanks.

EDIT: there are other texts in this document, too. For example:

```
SHIP TO LESSEE (EQUIPMENT location address): «UTTD_Equip_StreetAddress_TE», «UTTD_Equip_City_TE», «UTTD_Equip_State_MC»
```

Basically, I'm trying to index RTF files, and inside each RTF file is tables with variables. Variables are wrapped with `«` and `»` . I'm trying to search those variables in the documents. I've tried searching `"«" + string + "»"`, but it hasn't worked...

This example could give a better picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LQWJ.png

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

KeywordAnalyzer tokenizes the entire field as a single string. It sounds like this might be what you're looking for, if the substrings are in different fields within your document.

See: [KeywordAnalyzer](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_0_1/api/all/org/apache/lucene/analysis/KeywordAnalyzer.html)

Instead, if you are adding the entire content of the document within a single field, and you want to search for a substring with embedded '_' characters within it, then I would think that WhitespaceAnalyzer would work. You stated that it didn't work, though. Can you tell us what the results were when you tried using WhitespaceAnalyzer? And did you use it for both Indexing and Querying?

Comment: Should I use KeywordAnalyzer for both indexing and searching? Or searching only? Thanks, jwismar.

Comment: In the normal case, you will want your indexing and searching analyzer to be the same. From your description, I think this will work for you here.

Comment: There are other texts in this document, too. For example: ... SHIP TO LESSEE (EQUIPMENT location address): «UTTD_Equip_StreetAddress_TE», «UTTD_Equip_City_TE», «UTTD_Equip_State_MC» .... If I use KeywordAnalyzer and try to search for UTTD_Equip_City_TE, would this still work?

Comment: Are those all in the same field? If so, then KeywordAnalyzer might not be the right choice. Can you edit your question and give a few more details?

Comment: I just edited my question above. Could you take a look at it? Thanks jwismar.

Answer (score 0):

I see two options here. In both cases you have to build a custom analyzer.

**Option 1**

Start with StandardTokenizer's grammar file and customize it so that it emits text separated  by '_' as a single token. (refer to [Generating a custom Tokenizer for new TokenStream API using JFlex/ Java CC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846305/generating-a-custom-tokenizer-for-new-tokenstream-api-using-jflex-java-cc)). Build your Analyzer using this new Tokenizer along with LowerCaseFilter.

**Oprion 2**

Write a Custom Analyzer that is made of WhiteSpaceTokenizer and custom TokenFilters. In these TokenFilters you decide on how to act on the tokens returned by WhiteSpaceTokenizer.

Refer to http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/package-summary.html for more details on analysis